# webpack -p disables es2015 features in my ejs templates

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, ejs

I have a simple webpack setup for my project which uses ejs-templating on the front-end:

```
<ul>
  <% for (let station of stations) { %>
    <li>
      <strong><%= station.name %></strong>
      <br/>
      Coach Code: <%= station.nationalcoachcode %><br/>
      Distance:  <%= (station.distance / 1000 ).toFixed(1) %> km
    </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

This works great when I serve it with `webpack-dev-server` or build it with `webpack`, but when I try get a minified build with `webpack -p`, it can't process the for-of loop anymore and gives me the following error:

`ERROR in app.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token name «station», expected punc «;» [./~/ejs-loader!./src/app/stations.tmpl.ejs:7,0]`

this is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require ( 'html-webpack-plugin' );
const webpack = require ( 'webpack' );

const PATHS = {
  app: path.join( __dirname , 'src' ),
  build : path.join( __dirname , 'build' )
};

module.exports = {

  entry: {
    app: PATHS.app
  },

  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename : '[name].js'
  },

  devtool: 'source-map',

  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.ejs$/,
      loader: 'ejs-loader'
    }]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json', 'ejs']
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(PATHS.app, 'index.ejs')
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      _: "lodash"
    })
  ]

};
```

[edit]: I've already tried running the ejs templates through babel first, but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

My English is bad :( Just look at the code:

```
module: {
  preLoaders: [
    {
      test: /\.ejs$/, loader: 'ejs-compiled'
    }
  ],
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.e?js$/, // <-- look!
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: "babel-loader",
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
    }
  ]
},
'ejs-compiled-loader': {
  htmlmin: true,
  htmlminOptions: {
    removeComments: true
  },
  _with: false // <-- important!!!
}
```

And in EJS

```
<% var {station} = locals; %>
<ul>
  <% for (let station of stations) { %>
    <li>
      <strong><%= station.name %></strong>
      <br/>
      Coach Code: <%= station.nationalcoachcode %><br/>
      Distance:  <%= (station.distance / 1000 ).toFixed(1) %> km
    </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

I hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work for me either. With this config, it now gives me an error `ReferenceError: htmlWebpackPlugin is not defined`

Comment: Also, is it possible that in the .ejs file you need to get `stations` from locals, not `station`?

Comment: if you disable `with` (_with: false) then `station` is undefined. `var station = locals.station`

Comment: It's ok, don't bother. This is getting way too hacky for way too little return. I'll just stick to using VanillaJS in my templates. Thank you though!!

Comment: hmm... maybe... can you make a mistake in the plugins? I have earned my version